# Ford figo 1.4 ambiente 2013 petrol model no pulse on my injectors

Tags: fuel-injectors

Hello I have a ford figo 1.4 ambiente 2013 model, I have done all the diagnostic without the diagnostic machine, the spark is there the fuel pump it's pumping, the problem is that I don't have fuel getting into my cylinder, the injectors don't have pulse and one thing is that my engine relay makes a clicking sound repeatly when I make a car on, any suggestions for this matter?

Answer (score 0):

> engine relay makes a clicking sound repeatly when I make a car on

Might you have a low battery? That sounds like your starter solenoid is trying to engage, but there is not enough juice in the battery.

Try putting a battery charger on it overnight.